# Which database type for log analysis?

Tags: mysql, performance, graph-databases, logfile, nosql

I am running a database for log analysis. At the moment I use a MySQL database and the table for my analysis looks like this:

- UUID
- REQUEST_ID
- REQUEST_TIMESTAMP
- RESPONSE_TIMESTAMP
- RUNTIME
- SERVER_NAME

I use this table to create views for each entry, for 5 minute aggregation and for a daily aggregation. I am inserting about 400.000 entries a day. At the moment there are about 70 Million rows in this table.

My actual problem is, that my queries are getting slow, my insert/update queries as well as my aggregation queries.

So I created a second table for my daily aggregation. Once a day a job will run, to make an aggregation for the last day. A second job will delete all entries which are older than 30 days from the original table.

My question:
Is this the right approach or would be a different table structure or even a another database (e.g. NoSQL, Graph-database, etc.) better?

Answer (score 1):

Don't index UUID unless you have to.  It is very random and that leads to lots of I/O.  See [*here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/guiduuid-performance/) .

Do build the Summary tables, as you discussed; they are the main way to make Data Warehousing perform well.  But, let's see what you have -- `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECTs`, plus table sizes.

How are you doing the ingesting?  [*Here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-high-speed-ingestion/) are some tips on scaling such.  400K/day and 70M in the table is no problem for MySQL.

Normalization of server_name (and maybe other columns) -- see the ingestion link.

Why are there Updates?  Logs tend not to ever need updates.  Summary tables might use bulk IODKU, which is sort of an update; is that what you use?

As for deleting old data, `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` with 32 partitions and use `DROP PARTITION` nightly.  This will be *much* faster than `DELETE`:  [*Partition tips*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/)

How much RAM?  Using InnoDB?  The 70M rows take about 7GB?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Under what conditions do you ever touch data older than a day?  If 'never', then caching should not be a problem.  If 'often', let's study those cases.